# Adobe Reader, can you edit docments using it? (Not create but edit them)

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

Can adobe reader be used to fill out a form in the .pdf format?

I know the full version of adobe can be used, as well as "Preview" from mac and foxit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two questions in your post

- Can I edit PDF's in Adobe Reader?
- Can I fill out PDF forms in Adobe Reader?

To question one: No you can not, You will need the professional Adobe Acrobat software
To question two: Yes, you can fill out forms in PDF files with Adobe Reader

Comment: "Yes, you can fill out forms in PDF files with Adobe Reader"... but only if there are form fields embedded in the PDF file. You cannot enter text in boxes which "looks" like form fields.

Comment: To see an example of a PDF file with a form you can fill in and save with Adobe Reader, see [Form 1040EZ in PDF format](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040ez.pdf) from the IRS.